# ¿Como puedo optimizar mi código PHP y conexiones MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola ando con un problema y es a la hora de optimizar o mejorar mi código PHP estuve haciendo uso de Base de datos que se basan en los resultado de un juego (Counter Strike 1.6) comento al respecto para que tengan una idea, desde el servidor del juego se suben datos como:

`idRegistro | idDatos | Personajes | Logros | Kills | Elo | Rango | Logro | Puntos`

Todo esto se almacena dentro de la tabla: ct_datos.

Mi código PHP que use para utilizar estos usar los datos de las columnas es el siguiente ->

```php
<?php include_once "head.php" ?>
<?php
    include_once "conexion.php";
    $sentencia = $db_ffa->query("SELECT * FROM ct_datos;");
    $datos_ffa = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
    <hr>
    <div class="card border-dark mb-3card text-warning bg-light mb-3 text-center">
            
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title"></h4>
            <p class="card-text"><b>Información de los jugadores registrados del FFA</b></p>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <th scope="row">ID</th>
                    <th>PERSONAJE</th>
                    <th>KILLS</th>
                    <th>ELO</th>
                    <th>PUNTOS</th>
                    <th>RANGOS</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach($datos_ffa as $datos_ffa){ ?>
                <tr class="table-primary">
                    
                    <td><?php echo $datos_ffa->idRegistro ?></td>
                    <td><a href="player.php?id=<?php echo $datos_ffa->idRegistro ?>"><?php echo $datos_ffa->Personaje ?></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo '<span class=text-danger>'.$datos_ffa->Kills.'</span>'; ?></td>
                    <td><?php if ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 200) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>200</span>'; //Unranked
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 688) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>688</span>'; //Silver I
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 1000){
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>1000</span>'; //Silver II
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 1500) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>1500</span>'; //Silver III
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 2000) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>2000</span>'; //Silver IV
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 3500) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>3500</span>'; //Silver Elite
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 4000) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>4000</span>'; //Silver Elite Master
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 4300) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>4300</span>'; //Gold Nova I
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 4700) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>4700</span>'; //Gold Nova II
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 5000) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>5000</span>'; //Gold Nova III
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 5100) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>5100</span>'; //Gold Nova Master
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 5400) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>5400</span>'; //Master Guardian I
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 5900) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>5900</span>'; //Master Guardian II
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 6100) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>6100</span>'; //Master Guardian Elite
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 6600) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>6600</span>'; //Distinguished Master Guardian
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 7000) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>7000</span>'; //Legendary Eagle
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 7300) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>7300</span>'; //Legendary Eagle Master
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 7600) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>7600</span>'; //Supreme Master First Class
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Elo <= 0) {
                            echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class=text-success>0</span>'; //The Global Elite
                        } ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '<span class=text-warning>'.$datos_ffa->Puntos.'</span>' ?></td>
                    <td><?php if ($datos_ffa->Rango == 0) {
                            echo "<span class='border-light'><img src='https://i.ibb.co/HHzfg5T/0.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 1) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/hDWSG8d/1.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 2){
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/dgSPLD9/2.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 3) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/Bc6jsjM/3.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 4) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/Bc6jsjM/3.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 5) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/3pnjRS7/4.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 6) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/GpkgZq0/5.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 7) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/b6F3PPF/6.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 8) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/JjB8JYH/7.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 9) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/kmrfpqH/8.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 10) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/HVzW4jF/9.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 11) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/7XMCzyV/10.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 12) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/q7s3Syr/11.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 13) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/hWSbXfh/12.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 14) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/P9GNsTk/13.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 15) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/6Dr0D41/14.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 16) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/qd5J8Rh/15.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 17) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/fX5nPZx/16.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 18) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/xFgd2jg/17.png'>";
                        } elseif ($datos_ffa->Rango == 19) {
                            echo "<img src='https://i.ibb.co/WVqzsg7/18.png'>";
                        } ?>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Quería saber si hay una mejor manera optimizar mi código PHP con la conexión a MySQL

Los datos se muestra con esta query `$datos_ffa->`

Como se darán cuenta los dos que mas ocupo para obtener IF/ELSEIF son **Elo** que obtiene un limite por ej: el primer Elo llega a los **200** el 2do Elo llega a **688** esto se usa como una referencia para cuando se llega al número de referencia este cambia de Elo automáticamente, luego Rango que es el que proporciona la imagen dependiendo el Rango del jugador un ejemplo: Unranked =

Este es el resultado del código ya con el css armado: [image: Imagen resultado]

Si pueden brindarme una ayuda o consejo para optimizar el código estaría muy agradecido.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta no se ajusta a lo que plantea el [help/on-topic]. No hay problemas en tu código, es decir, por lo que se aprecia, el mismo funciona. Tu planteamiento es: ***Quería saber si me pueden dar un consejo para optimizar mejor el uso de los resultados en la tabla así como también alguna librería para un mejor manejo con DB.***, lo cuál se interpreta como una pregunta que busca opiniones y no una solución a un problema específico. Te invito a repasar [ask], y lo que dice el [help/dont-ask] sobre el tipo de preguntas que debemos evitar en el sitio. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras he cambiado el titulo de la publicación a uno mas adecuado

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende. ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Qué has intentado para resolverlo?

Comment: @A.Cedano quiero saber si hay una forma de optimizar ese código ya que lo veo muy mal optimizado.

Comment: Yo también lo veo mal optimizado pero en la pregunta no explicas el problema. Por ejemplo, ¿todas las relaciones expresadas en esos `if` pueden reflejarse en una o varias tablas? Si es sí, ¿lo has intentado? ¿qué dificultades tienes? Si es no, ¿por qué no?

Comment: Si se reflejan todas bien, pero quiero ver si hay una forma de hacerlo mas optimizado, y no tan largo. Que consejo o ayuda me puedes dar para mejorar ese código.

Comment: Podrías por ejemplo guardar información de rangos con su valor asociado. Así vas guardando en dos columnas: `desde` y `hasta` pares de valores: `0` y `200` ,  `201` y `688` ... etc. Y luego harías una consulta verificando entre que rango está el valor dado, extrayendo la información que haya asociada a ese caso. De ese modo toda la lógica de los `if`  queda expresada en tu modelo de datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para este tipo de cosas, me gusta usar arreglos u objetos, ya sea que se codifiquen directamente o provengan de bases de datos:

Primero defines el arreglo con todas las opciones, comenzando con índice cero y puedes aprovechar para tener ahí mismo los títulos, seguramente los vas a usar en algún lado.

```
$badges = [
    0 => 'The global Elite',
    200 => 'Unranked',
    688 => 'Silver I',
    // Agrega todos los que necesites
    7600 => 'Supreme Master First Class',
    99999999 => 'El mejor de todos' // Un número alto para asegura que siempre se obtiene un valor
];
```

Cuando necesites mostrar, recorre el arreglo, si el valor es menor o igual al índice (`$badge`), se usa para crear el span y salir del ciclo con *break*

```
foreach($badges as $badge => $name) {
    if ($datos_ffa->Elo <= $badge) {
        echo '<span class="badge badge-dark"><span class=text-info>'.$datos_ffa->Elo.'</span> | <span class="text-success">' . $badge . '</span>';
        break:
    }
}
```

Lo mismo para las imágenes, creas tu arreglo y, simplemente, muestras de acuerdo al rango:

```
$ranges = [
    'https://i.ibb.co/hDWSG8d/1.png', // Rango 1 (índice cero)
    'https://i.ibb.co/dgSPLD9/2.png', // Rango 2
    'https://i.ibb.co/Bc6jsjM/3.png',
    'https://i.ibb.co/Bc6jsjM/3.png', // ...
    // Agrega todas las necesarias
    'https://i.ibb.co/WVqzsg7/18.png' // Rango 19 (índice 18)
];
// $datos_ffa->Rango - 1 para acceder a la imagen correcta
echo '<img src="' . $ranges[$datos_ffa->Rango - 1] . '">';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido y ahora tengo una mejor visión para armar los for each!